# Loading a new view from selected row in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `searchDisplayController` to search for scripts in the financial app that I'm working on. My requirement is that when the user selects a row from the `searchDisplayController`'s `searchResultsTableview`, a new view should be shown taking up the space occupied by the `searchResultsTableview`, with the details of the selected item. I'm stuck at this point and did not find anything useful after searching for a whole day on the Internet. Also, my `searchDisplayController` does not cover the `navigationBar` as it should, by default. Please help. Any tutorial or ideas on this welcome... Thanks in advance!

NOTE: I use xib files for creating the UI. Xcode version 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using navigation controller to manage multiple views? If you have details to display on selection of a row I would suggest using a nav controller.

Comment: hi.. I am using a navigation controller and also tried pushing the detail view from within the  searchResultsTableView. But the new view did not get pushed into the stack. Isn't there other ways of displaying the detail view other than using the navigation controller?